# Array to multiple column in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

```
Input format()
[20201222,abc:"123",qwe:"Mobile",poi:"testing",oki:"keys",kju:"Tesint"]
[20201222,abc:"923",qwe:"tables",poi:"testing",oki:"lock",kju:"Tesint",juh:"mac",nbg:"oops",url:"links"]
[20201222,abc:"763",qwe:"Mac",poi:"testing",oki:"lock",kju:"Tesint",jyh:"897"]
[20201222,abc:"14",qwe:"desk",poi:"testing",oki:"lock",kju:"Tesint",origin:"git",push:"yes"]
[20201222,abc:"198",qwe:"lappy",poi:"testing",oki:"keys",kju:"Tesint"]
[20201222,abc:"1043",qwe:"Mobile",poi:"testing",oki:"bitlocker",kju:"Tesint"]

expected output 
abc  | qwe    | poi     | oki     |  kju  | juh |nbg |url  | jyh |origin | push
================================================================================
123  | mobile | testing | keys    |Tesing | null|null|null | null|null|null
923  | tables | tesitng | lock    |Tesing | mac |oops|links|null|null |null
763  | Mac    | testing | lock    |Tesing | null|null|null| 897 |null | null
14   | desk   | testing | lock    |Tesing | null|null|null| null| git | yes
198  | lappy  | testing | keys    |Tesing | null|null|null| null|null | null
1043 | mobile | testing |bitlocker|Tesing | null|null|null| null|null | null
```

*I read entire file with single column and converted into array with C1 column
I tried to all possible scenario whatever i know. finally failed
Can any once help me please using pyspark*

Answer (score 0):

You need to manipulate the string manually, so it's a bit ugly, but not impossible:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df = spark.read.text('input.txt').toDF('text')

df2 = (df.selectExpr(
    "monotonically_increasing_id() id",
    "split(replace(substr(text, 2, length(text) - 2), '\"', ''), ',') arr"
).select('id', F.explode('arr'))
 .selectExpr('id', "str_to_map(col, ',', ':') col")
 .select('id', F.explode('col'))
 .groupBy('id')
 .pivot('key')
 .agg(F.first('value'))
)

df3 = df2.select(df2.columns[2:])

df3.show()
+----+----+----+------+----+---------+------+-------+----+------+-----+
| abc| juh| jyh|   kju| nbg|      oki|origin|    poi|push|   qwe|  url|
+----+----+----+------+----+---------+------+-------+----+------+-----+
| 123|null|null|Tesint|null|     keys|  null|testing|null|Mobile| null|
|1043|null|null|Tesint|null|bitlocker|  null|testing|null|Mobile| null|
| 923| mac|null|Tesint|oops|     lock|  null|testing|null|tables|links|
|  14|null|null|Tesint|null|     lock|   git|testing| yes|  desk| null|
| 763|null| 897|Tesint|null|     lock|  null|testing|null|   Mac| null|
| 198|null|null|Tesint|null|     keys|  null|testing|null| lappy| null|
+----+----+----+------+----+---------+------+-------+----+------+-----+
```

Comment: Am getting exception using above code.( Not able to find text)Can you please help me on that

Comment: @MyMacMyLife did you use my code to read in the file as well? you need to use `spark.read.text` and use `toDF('text')` so that the dataframe has one column called `text`.

Comment: Thank you so much @mck. Currently am running code with 300GB File. I able to reading file so quick and While applying transformation logic (above code logic)  my code is failing. With small data(1GB) code is going fine and getting matching records. Can you please help me. How can i move forward . I struggling  with code past week days for processing 300gb files.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps, the following approach would solve the problem without much string manipulations. Since you have't mentioned your source type,I assume it's file thus my solution is based on files.

```
val fields = Array(
        StructField("dummy", StringType, true),
        StructField("abc", StringType, true),
        StructField("qwe", StringType, true),
        StructField("poi", StringType, true),
        StructField("oki", StringType, true),
        StructField("kju", StringType, true))

      val newSchema = StructType(fields)

      //Read the file as CSV instead of txt 
      val baseDf = spark.read.schema(newSchema).option("inferschema", "true").option("sep", ",").csv("/data.txt")
        .drop("dummy")
 
      //Prepare clean-up expression for all the columns.Assuming all the columns are string type.
      val expressions = baseDf.schema.fields.map { field =>
       val temp = regexp_replace(col(field.name), "^[a-zA-Z]+:", "").alias(field.name)
        regexp_replace(temp,"\"|]","").alias(field.name)
      }

      baseDf.select(expressions: _*).show(false)
```

**Output**

```
+----+------+-------+---------+------+
|abc |qwe   |poi    |oki      |kju   |
+----+------+-------+---------+------+
|123 |Mobile|testing|keys     |Tesint|
|923 |tables|testing|lock     |Tesint|
|763 |Mac   |testing|lock     |Tesint|
|14  |desk  |testing|lock     |Tesint|
|198 |lappy |testing|keys     |Tesint|
|1043|Mobile|testing|bitlocker|Tesint|
+----+------+-------+---------+------+
```

Comment: Data bot having fixed columns so sometimes wont come columns and currently am getting more then 60 columns. Is there any dynamic way do we have???

Comment: can you please explain your scenario in bit more detail ?  your comment is not clear.

Comment: Thank for respond on my post. @mck code is working fine for less data. if we want process 300GB above file code is falling . So can you please help me on. how can i move forward. (Parallel processing)